# how to limit the additions field in jsonschema where they is undeclare

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

In json object some field is not what i need,but they still through my validation,like below.

The jsonchema：

```py
my_schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 1,
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["endpoint", "bucket"],
        "properties": {
            "endpoint": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "bucket": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
            },
            "dir": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The jsons:

```
one = [{
    "endpoint": "",
    "bucket": "2020-10-27 16:20:24",
    "dir": "/tmp"
}]
two = [{
    "endpoint": "",
    "bucket": "2020-10-27 16:20:24",
    "dir": "/tmp",
    "id": "leaking"
}]
```

And i run this code in python2.7:

```
import jsonschema
from jsonschema import validate

print(jsonschema.__version__)
validate(instance=one, schema=my_schema)
validate(instance=two, schema=my_schema)  # how can i let this line raise a Exception?

print("validated one, two.")
```

Output:

```
3.2.0
passed one, two.  # this not my intention
```

The foregoing json `two` have a field "`id`" need to be excluded, and any fields not declared in "`properties`" are treated the same way.

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: no any output(raise a Exception).

Answer (score 2):

Use `additionalProperties`

> The additionalProperties keyword is used to control the handling of extra stuff, that is, properties whose names are not listed in the properties keyword. By default any additional properties are allowed.

> The additionalProperties keyword may be either a boolean or an object. If additionalProperties is a boolean and set to false, no additional properties will be allowed.

From [docs](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html)

Your schema would look like:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 1,
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["endpoint", "bucket"],
        "properties": {
            "endpoint": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "bucket": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
            },
            "dir": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
}
```